# Network Setup with 18.04 server

Tags: networking, server

I've been having trouble with my network setup since I did an upgrade recently. It used to work but now IP traffic isn't getting through as it once did, everything else seems to work though. I have asked a question about this before but now I'm going to ask about how to set up my network from the ground up. My network looks like this:-

```
 Client PCs   |--------|
  Windows-----|        |                |----------------|
   Linux(1)---| Switch |-------------(2)| Server (18.04) |(3)-------Internet
  Printer-----|        |                |----------------|
 Other PCs----|        |
              |--------|
```

(1) ifconfig output from Linux PC on private network:-

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:66:82:61:f7  
      inet addr:192.168.1.126  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4829 (4.8 KB)  TX bytes:8871 (8.8 KB)
      Interrupt:23 Base address:0xa800 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:10976 (10.9 KB)  TX bytes:10976 (10.9 KB)
```

(2) Ethernet ID: enp5s0

(3) Ethernet ID: enp0s31f6

And the yaml netplan file on the server is:-

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
    enp0s31f6:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.5/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

The server is also running dnsmasq which provides the DHCP and DNS services which seem to be working correctly, pinging a site by name (e.g. "ping stackoverflow.com") on a client PC does get an IP address but then fails to do the actual ping.

Also, "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" is set to "1".

Have I missed something blindingly obvious?

If you need to know anything else, leave a comment and I'll update the question with the information.

Comment: Sounds like a NAT problem at the Server. Namely, did you set up the NAT `MASQUERADE` rules in `iptables` for the network so that the system knows to `MASQUERADE` all traffic heading out to the Internet as that interface's IP address, and so it can do the dynamic NATting back to the source IPs of that related response traffic to the internal network addresses?

Comment: No, there are no iptables rules. How do you do that? (I'm a software guy, not a network guy :-(  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing here is **NAT rules** so the system knows how to route traffic from inside the network to outside.  However, we have a problem here:  You've provided us to network interfaces, **both of which have private IPv4 addresses**.  This makes handling the NAT rules a little trickier.

Given, though, that only one interface has a gateway (`enp0s31f6`) I will be operating under the assumption that that interface is the Internet-connected interface.

NAT stands for **Network Address Translation**.  If you want to know more about how NAT works, [there is a decent layman's guide to NAT produced by the How Stuff Works (.com) website](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm) if you want to learn a little bit more about how NAT works.

The actual *description* of how NAT behaves is not as relevant to answering this question, but basically, it takes packets going to the Internet from the private IP space (with the source address of 192.168.0.10 for example), and translates the packet before rebroadcasting to the Internet (typically) so that the 'Source' address looks like the public IP address of the router.  This NAT 'session' is remembered until the connections for that session are terminated, which means the router can also do the reverse NAT rules so the Internet's packets end up properly at the internal IP address.  (The How Stuff Works guide is better than this at explaining NAT; this is just a quick and dirty description)

---

Now, to make your 'router' work.

You need to add NAT rules so that the **private subnet** (on `enp5s0`) is permitted to go out to the Internet posing as the server.  This is called a `MASQUERADE` in `iptables` terminology.  This is how the standard off-the-shelf routers work, and they all use NAT to translate the private IPv4 addresses into public ones so that communication with the Internet behaves seamlessly.

This is the command you should start with:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 ! -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Let me break down this so you can understand what this rule is actually doing.

- `sudo iptables` - Execute the `iptables` command as superuser.
- `-t nat` - Adjust the NAT rules on the system instead of the Firewall access control/filtering lists.
- `-A POSTROUTING` - Add to the post-routing NAT table.
- `-s 192.168.1.0/24` - Match on traffic originating from the private IP subnet...
- `! -d 192.168.1.0/24` - ... where the destination IP address is *not* the private IP space of the subnet...
- `-j MASQUERADE` - ... and retransmit this packet over the primary network interface (in this case, `enp0s31f6`), translating the packets' IP address so it looks like it originated from the 'router' / server to anything seeing the packet outside of the private IP space.

So, a packet originating from 192.168.1.10 going to a server on an IP address outside of 192.168.1.0-255 will look like, to that other server, that the packet originated from 192.168.0.5 (your server), instead of the origin of 192.168.1.10.  The system will remember this translation, though, so that it can take response packets destined to 192.168.0.5 and make sure they are properly addressed to return to your 192.168.1.10 address.

---

**However, there is one problem: this will not be saved after a reboot.**

So you should install the `iptables-persistent` package so that this NAT rule is reloaded every single time you boot.**

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent
```

When it prompts you to save current IPv4 and IPv6 rules, you should select "Yes".

---

Also, this 'default' of not having any firewall rules, while good in theory, **makes your system vulnerable to attack from the Internet at large**, and you should really touch base with any of the basic `iptables` guides on how to properly secure the server/router so that the outside can't directly attack the server.  This is, however, outside the scope of your original question, and if you want assistance with better securing the private network from the Outside ("Internet"), then you should consider asking that as its own question.

Comment: I thought it might be the iptables, did restart the server but didn't have the tables persisited. I'd forgotten how I set them up or even had them running, seems OK for now (and I've created a shell script with this in and installed the iptables-persistent package so I'm doubly better off!). As for firewall, in the diagram the "Internet" bit is actually a cable to my Virgin Media modem and that's set up to only allow traffic on Port 80 / 443(?) through.